# Pass arguments to gradle task from command line

Tags: gradle, groovy

How do I access the value of an argument from the command line in a gradle task? I know that this can be done by `-P` but I have the same property in my properties file and gradle picks the argument from the properties file rather than the command line. How do I prioritize accepting arguments from the command line over the properties file?

**build.gradle**

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream("./local.properties"))
props.each { prop ->
    project.ext.set(prop.key, prop.value)
}

task print {
    println("Gets = ${remote}");
}
```

**local.properties**

```
remote=from_properties
```

**Command from cmd**

```
gradle print -Premote=from_commandline
```

**Output**

Gets = from_properties

Comment: Why don't you just use the `gradle.properties` file supported by Gradle?

Comment: I have different property files from different environments like local, stage, prod etc

Comment: how do you plan to inject the properties file to be loaded? in your example you hardcoded the loading of `local.properties` and doing this, you break the Gradle properties precedence rule (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html ) . maybe you could simply implement a check to avoid properties override? like  :  `props.each { prop ->
    if (!project.hasProperty(prop.key))  project.ext.set(prop.key, prop.value)
}`

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I am hardcoding the file for the sake of simplicity. Here all i want is to find a way how i can prioritize the command line argument over a property in the properties file when the argument and the property both have the same name.

Comment: @ParagKadam I understand. did you test the "workaround" I proposed ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use your own local.properties file if you intend to use a properties file for Gradle properties.

Just use `gradle.properties` instead.

Also notice that you shouldn't declare task code inside its configuration block, you need to use `doFirst` or `doLast`:

**gradle.properties**

```
remote = properties
```

**build.gradle**

```
task print {
    doLast { println "Gets = ${remote}" }
}
```

If you run `./gradlew print` you will see `Gets = properties`.

If you run `./gradlew print -Premote=foo` you should see `Gets = foo`.

---

That said.... if you really want your own properties file, you need to implement the order of priority yourself, Gradle cannot guess what you prefer.

For example, you could check if a property is already set before setting it:

```
def props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream("./local.properties"))
props.each { key, value ->
    if (!project.hasProperty(key)) {
      project.ext.set(key, value)
    }
}
```